# How to check ALL methods are true before performing an action

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an issue in that I'm implementing approximately 5 validation checks in a form. Each of these is located in its own method `Is_XXX_Valid()`. I'm looking for a way to establish that each of the methods `return true;` otherwise an error message should be displayed.

This however is where the problem arises, I have a solution which works partially, in that it fails to run the subsequent methods if a previous method has returned `false`

Here is the current code which I am using:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    DialogResult validation_msgbox = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you would like to submit this form?", "Submit Form?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    // Run each validaion check

    if (IsAAAValid() && IsBBBValid())
    {
      //Continue and submit data
    }
    else
    {
      //Display the errors
      DialogResult Textbox_validation = MessageBox.Show(ErrorText, "Some errors were found.", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
  }
```

Using the code above as an example, if `IsAAAValid()` returns false, then the second method is not executed and therefore the data within is not validated, leading to an incorrect dialog box if multiple errors are found.

Thanks!

Comment: `&&` is short-circuiting, so the first false return will cause any subsequent conditionals not to execute. Simply use `&` instead, as it is not short-circuiting.

Comment: Can't you just do bool variables for each method call, and do an if () over the bool variables?

Comment: If you truly need all methods to run, then I think your method's responsibilities are not well named/defined.  I wouldn't expect a method named `IsXXX` to have side effects like what you are implying.

Answer (score 8):

This is known as "short-circuit evaluation," which you can read about [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) and is a usually-desirable feature of the C# programming language.  You can get around it with something like this:

```
bool avalid = IsAAAValid();
bool bvalid = IsBBBValid();
if (avalid && bvalid)
{
  //Continue and submit data
}
```

This will guarantee that both methods get run.

As a side note, for clarity in your code I would recommend that you rename your validation methods to signify that they have side-effects.  That is, they do more than simply returning the state of the data; they actually have the potential to modify state.  This is why short-circuit evaluation causes problems in this instance.

Answer (score 6):

As `adv12` has answered, this is called short-circuit evaluation but there is also an alternative to the way he refactored your code.

There are two boolean *and* operators:

- `&&` - short-circuit evaluation
- `&` - full evaluation

So you can simply switch to using `&` to call both methods regardless:

```
if (IsAAAValid() & IsBBBValid())
                 ^
                 |
                 +-- only one &, not two &&
```

Now, having said that, personally I would write the code as [adv12](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1771817/adv12) did as it makes for easier to read code, not as easy to spot the use of only the one `&` but I thought I would post the answer for completeness.

Comment: Nice answer, especially recommendation to not do that :). It is pretty much guaranteed that next person who see the code will replace `&` with `&&` and call original author names... and than week later spend a day trying to figure out why code no longer reports errors correctly.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yeah, relying on side effects within a boolean expression is pretty sketchy.  But breaking things up and recording results is more readable.

Answer (score 4):

You could simply call every method and sets a boolean value to false if any of the methods return false. At the end you could check this boolean value and display your error message.

```
bool isValid = true;
if(!IsValidA()) isValid = false;
if(!IsValidB()) isValid = false;
if(!IsValidC()) isValid = false;
if(!IsValidD()) isValid = false;
if(!IsValidE()) isValid = false;
if(!isValid)
    MessageBox.Show("Global validation error message");
```

However I prefer a better approach in which you use a `List<string>` to accumulate error messages and print them all at the end

```
List<string> errors = new List<string>();
if(!IsValidA()) errors.Add("Fail on IsValidA");
if(!IsValidB()) errors.Add("Fail on IsValidB");
if(!IsValidC()) errors.Add("Fail on IsValidC");
if(!IsValidD()) errors.Add("Fail on IsValidD");
if(!IsValidE()) errors.Add("Fail on IsValidE");

if(errors.Count > 0)
{
    string message = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, errors.ToArray());
    MessageBox.Show("Validation errors found:" + Environment.NewLine + message);
}
```

I think this is better from a user perspective because you could inform her/him of the problems found in a single message and avoid that horrible user experience that happens when you tell to your user about a single problem, the user fixes the problem only to be awarded with another error message about another problem.

Comment: Replacing the count in the first code example with a boolean, e.g. `notValid`, would remove the need to test for `5` and update the value if the tests change during future code maintenance. The second code example is highly recommended for communicating useful information back to the user.

Comment: right, it will be a little more confusing but nevertheless you are correct

Comment: Would using `isValid &= IsValidA(); ...` be more appealing? It doesn't short circuit.